# Embedding a case label in an if...else statement

Tags: c++

G++ accepts this code and it behaves as I'd expect it to:

```
#include <cassert>

void example (int value, bool condition) {

  switch (value) {
  case 0:
    if (condition) {
  case 1:
      assert(condition || value == 1);
    } else {
      assert(!condition && value == 0);
    }
    assert(value == 0 || value == 1);
  }

}

int main () {
  example(0, false);
  example(1, false);
  example(0, true);
  example(1, true);
}
```

Maybe this is a silly basic question but, code smell aside, is it valid C++ to put a `case` label inside an `if...else` block, and will all well-behaved compilers correctly generate code that will jump over the `else` block when entered through `case 1`?

Comment: can you post a minimal compilable example?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore There you go.

Comment: compiles on visual studio 2012 and behaves as you describe with `int value = 1;  bool condition = false;`

Comment: `gcc` is a C compiler and I just ran this example totally in C. I don't see anything particularly C++ about this question. You don't have a C label. It's very odd and butt-ugly, and I'm surprised the C compiler allows it. But it does. I think it is because once inside the `switch` statement, the C syntax just sees the `case` as a computed label. You can put any kind of constructs in there you wish: `while`, `for`, etc, and jump right in the middle of them with a `case` label. It's a special kind of `goto` label, in essence.

Comment: @mbratch Thanks! As for C; yes it may happen to compile as C. As `g++` is commonly referred to as the product named GCC ([for example](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php)), I didn't think it would be misleading, but I will clarify.

Comment: I'm not saying it's misleading. I just think it's mislabeled. I think it's all about C, really, as it pertains to C constructs which are, of course, recognized by C++ as well. By the way, when I run `gcc` on the command line on a C++ file it yells at me. I have to use `g++`. ;)

Comment: @mbratch `goto` labels will behave the same way? A label in the `if` part of an `if..else` will always cause the `else` block to be correctly skipped, and won't "confuse" any compilers that, say, want to optimize the `if..else` by reorganizing it somehow?

Comment: I did play with `goto` and labels here or there inside the `if-else` and it does seem to behave as expected and same as `case` inside the `switch`. Not a totally comprehensive test, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as C++ is concerned (draft N3936):

- case and default labels in themselves do not alter the flow of control, **which continues unimpeded across such labels**.
- Usually, the substatement that is the subject of a switch is compound and case and default labels appear on the top-level statements contained within the (compound) substatement, **but this is not required**.(§ 6.4.2 - 6)
- **It is possible to transfer into a block**, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. (§ 6.7 - 3)

What you are doing is technically ok, of course that doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Thanks for digging that up! This is exactly the kind of info I was looking for (going to wait a few more minutes to see if any "language lawyers" appear). It seems like "but this is not required" is the big one there that implicitly allows strange cases like the one in the example.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is perfectly standard C++ code, although I don't think it is particularly easy to read or maintain. If we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `6.4` *Selection statements* the grammar for switch statement is as follows:

```
switch ( condition ) statement
```

statements include labels, if, while, for etc... and section `6.4.2` *The switch statement* poses no restrictions that would preclude the code that you are showing.

Case labels are just like the labels used with a *goto*, which is covered in section `6.1` *Labeled statement* but they are restricted to being used in a *switch statement*:

> Case labels and default labels shall occur only in switch statements.

and section `6.7` says we can transfer into a block given some restrictions such as not bypassing a declaration with an initialization:

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps<sup>87</sup> from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared without an initializer (8.5).

footnote `87` says:

> The transfer from the condition of a switch statement to a case label is considered a jump in this respect.

Probably, one of the most famous and strangest uses of a switch statement would be [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) which has an embedded `while` loop:

```
void send( int *to, const int *from, int  count)
{
        int n = (count + 7) / 8;
        switch(count % 8) 
        {
            case 0: do {    *to = *from++;   // <- Scope start
            case 7:         *to = *from++;
            case 6:         *to = *from++;
            case 5:         *to = *from++;
            case 4:         *to = *from++;
            case 3:         *to = *from++;
            case 2:         *to = *from++;
            case 1:         *to = *from++;
                        } while(--n > 0);    // <- Scope end
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Great example; I *have* seen that before, I forgot all about it!